# Message;no such element(selenium xpath)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I have a problem with selenium `find_by_xpath`

This is my xpath : `//input [@type='text']`

And I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKkiA.png)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input [@type='text']"}
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
username="123456"
password="123456"
url="https://www.foxesscloud.com/login"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input [@type='text']").send_keys("Pies123")
print("done")

print("Log")
```

Comment: Do not post code as image, but rather as text. Doing so would create a mandatory [mcve] for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `Elements are not rendered properly` and you are trying to interact with them. Please use Explicit wait to handle this situation and error.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.foxesscloud.com/login")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input [@type='text']"))).send_keys('Pies123')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input [@type='password']"))).send_keys('Your password here')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.login-click"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, everything works fine now.